# Roboletric: How to test fragments opened after button pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, robolectric

I have some flows where a fragment opens another fragment to do staff in a dedicated screen. Every time I open the new fragment Roboletric is not able to "see" the stuff in the new fragment. Sometimes adding `inRoot{ isDialog }` solves the problem, other times it doesn't.

Any idea on how to work on this? Using espresso + actual device everything works correctly but I would want to move the tests to roboletric to use JVM instead of a real device.

Comment: In case of ```espresso``` it is usually done via ```IdlingResource```. I haven't worked with robolectric for five years, not sure what should be an equivalent to this there.

Comment: I think that idling is not enough in this case, the fragment is not found. However, how would you do it? So I can try :)

Comment: by link below you can take a look on how to I did similar test case in espresso: https://github.com/Gelassen/government-rus/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/ru/home/government/screens/laws/details/LawDetailsFragmentTest.kt#L156

Answer (score 0):

To test fragments that are opened after a button is pressed, you can use the Robolectric framework, which allows you to perform unit testing on Android app code. Here are the general steps you can follow:

Create a test class that extends the RobolectricTestRunner class.
In the test class, create a method that simulates the button press and opens the fragment.
Use the startFragment method provided by Robolectric to start the fragment and add it to the activity.
Use the getSupportFragmentManager method to get the fragment manager and use the findFragmentById method to find the fragment that is currently displayed.
Use assertNotNull to check that the fragment is not null, indicating that it has been successfully opened.
Perform any additional tests on the fragment's views or behavior as needed.
Here is an example of what the test method might look like:

```
@Test
public void testFragmentOpensAfterButtonPress() {
    // Simulate button press
    button.performClick();

    // Start the fragment
    startFragment(new MyFragment());

    // Find the fragment
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    // Assert that the fragment is not null
    assertNotNull(fragment);

    // Perform additional tests on the fragment's views or behavior
    ...
}
```

Comment: this code is quite old and deprecated. I've tried with this but it doesn't work as well:

            val activityScenario = launchActivity<DashboardActivity>()
            activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
            activityScenario.onActivity {
                val fragment: Fragment = it.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
                    Preconditions.checkNotNull(AddRoutineFragment::class.java.classLoader),
                    AddRoutineFragment::class.java.name
                )
                launchFragment { fragment }.onFragment {